# Finding exact location of bytes in function

Tags: c, linux

I am inserting a byte in a function:

```
void func_simple(){
    ...
    asm volatile (
        ".align 4 \n"
        ".long 0xfafafafa \n"
    );
    ...
}
```

How can I calculate how many bytes are before and after the inserted byte in `func_simple`? With `nm -S a.out | grep func_simple` I can get the begin address and length of `func_simple`, but I do not know how to go further.

Comment: You may need to elaborate a bit further what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to perform such a calculation?  Whatever your ultimate objective, there is surely a better way to achieve it.

Comment: I expect the posted `asm` will show up on the stack, not embedded in the code,

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you could try the following:

```
void func_simple(){
    ...
    asm volatile (
    ".align 4 \n"
    ".global mydata \n"
    "mydata:\n"
    ".long 0xfafafafa \n"
    );
   ...
}
```

And then look for the symbol "mydata" with "objdump" or "nm -S"

Answer (score 0):

You can use objdump for looking at the entire object code which will specify the address and statements of the function.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.
You may try to use gdb for further analysis of how the code is working